# Need to show woo commerce notices twice on cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to duplicate the Woocommerce notices twice on the cart page. Once where they currently are above the cart items themselves. And once bellow the item.

Reason being that if there are a lot of items in the cart if someone uses a coupon or if there's an error you no longer see the message.

I have tried adding `wc_print_notices();` to where it should go into the template and it will only print the notices once. If I remove the first call the second will show up and vice versa.

I also tried to duplicate the `wc_print_notices()` function and rename with the same result, it will only print one at a time.

Is there something inside woo where it will only print the notices once per page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The last line of that function is `wc_clear_notices();` so, yes, it will only print the notices once.

However, there is another function further down (see https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_print_notices.html#118-141) called `wc_get_notices()`, so you could use that instead. It returns an array, so you'd need to process it further.

Alternatively, you could try copying the entire of the `wc_print_notices()` function to your own, just omitting the last line (although you will have to call `wc_clear_notices()` at some stage).